# PhpStorm starts indexing files on each launch

Tags: phpstorm

I am not sure if this is desired behaviour, but PhpStorm (8.0.3) proceeds to index all files and directories each time I open the IDE. The indexing takes too long - half hour and more. During that time I'm not able to access many configuration options or use "Go to definition" option.

It is very irritating. Shouldn't PhpStorm somehow cache the indices so that it does not go through the whole process over and over again?

It seems that the problem grew over time and at this time it totally paralizes my ability to work on projects.

Is there a solution to it that you know of?

Comment: It is not the normal behaviour. Try the command `Invalidate Caches/Restart` in the `File` menu. It should fix it (after it restarts and successfully finishes the cache rebuild).

Comment: Suggestions: Try `File | Invalidate caches...` and restart IDE. If it will continue doing reindexing on each launch -- maybe consider removing index/cache files manually ([location depends on your OS](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)). If still nothing -- try deleting `.idea` subfolder (project settings; make backup first; IDE must be closed when deleting it, of course) and reconfigure project from scratch (possibly some files are corrupted somehow)

Comment: you lost parameter PHPStorm with any reason or your file system move dangerously without you know....

Comment: I may also suggest checking latest PhpStorm versions (can be run in parallel to your current version: stable v10.0.3 and v11 EAP build). You just need to make backup of your project settings (`.idea` subfolder) if you plan to go back to v8 after checking this project in newer version -- some changes in project settings are not backward compatible (the IDE-wide settings are stored in separate folders any way so they are safe)

Answer (score 2):

Try right-clicking file -> invalidate caches and restart. It worked for me!

Comment: This works for me, Problem maybe was because of moving my project to new folder .

Answer (score 2):

```
File ==> Manage IDE Settings ==> Restore Default Settings
```

And now it loads rapidly

Comment: this is what i had to do at last after following many other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

is this problem still current? It's more than year since question, so it could be fixed already.

There is no reliable way to say why it's happenings without seeing the logs.

You may try this:

1. Close IDE (or this project at least)
2. Backup and delete .idea subfolder (this project settings)
3. Launch IDE and using "Open" point to the project root -- IDE will create new project from those files
4. Reconfigure your project as needed
5. Restart IDE / close-reopen project (do what you did in the past where it lead to project re-indexing)
6. It's better now?
7. If yes, and you have not re-configured ALL aspects of the project yet -- then you may re-use some of the files from previously
   made backup (while IDE/project is closed, of course)

Comment: Hi, since that time I started using a newer version of PHPStorm and the problem disappeared. No idea what was causing it. Now I switched to another IDE and will not be digging into it. Thanks for your instruction. It might help people who're experiencing a similar issue.

Comment: Ok, this can solve the problem, but with a big cost of redoing lot of configurations manually... for a simple project, ok, but for a big project it can be hours of work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after searching a while I understood that `.gitignore` plugin caused it.

After disabling mentioned plugin ide backed to work correctly again.